# Is it possible to update my listview witouth moving to first row?

Tags: android, android-listview

I know there were plenty of similar problems there but I didn't find specific problem like that. What I expect? After I update my row by setOnItemClickListener I want to update my listview from database and see it updated without screen moving to first row every time I update listview. How it works right now?

```
                    dbWorker.fillList();
                    ArrayList<Uni> List = StaticVariables.List;
                    final listviewAdapterList adapterList = new listviewAdapterList(ListActivity.this, List);
                    lvList.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

I know that I can somehow use notifyDataSetChanged() but I'm not quiet sure where should I use it to not move list from row I clicked to first row.

Comment: Do not create a new adapter to begin with. Just update the list for the adapter. (The data set). Then call notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: @blackapps So it should look like that: dbworker.fillList() than list = StaticVariables.List, than adapterList.notifydatasetchanged and thats all?

Comment: If 'list'  is the data set of the adapter then yes. But i think it's not. I dont know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Comment: Also you can remember and restore first visible item of the list view.